# How to get fragment width?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Here is my layout.I need to get the width in CategoryFragment.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/category_list"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/pianodule_list"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
            android:id="@id/refreshable_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:divider="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/divider_line" />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.srefu.frag.CategoryFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="category" />
</LinearLayout>
```

so in  onViewCreated() of CategoryFragment I try several way to achieve it but all not work.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    View v = view;
    // View v = getView(); 
    int w1 = v.getWidth(); //return 0
    int w2 = v.getLayoutParams().width; //return NullPointerException
    int w3 = v.getMeasuredWidth(); //return 0
}
```

how should i do can i get width of fragment?Any help will  is appreciated .Thanks. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you are calling getWidth() too early.
Try below mentioned code. Hope it helps you

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                view.getHeight(); //height is ready
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Fantastic,it work for me!I agree with you that i calling getWith() too early.Thanks.:)

Comment: Don't forget to remove the globallayoutlistener once you get the height, otherwise you may have a leak. You should use removeOnGlobalLayoutListener right after getting the height, if you just need it one time.